# Winter Bash 2016 site background image not displayed properly in Landscape (mobile device)

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash-2016

The [winterbash-2016](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2016) [website](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com) looks like this on mobile Landscape orientation:

> [image]

Portrait rotation is better:

> [image]

Scrolling up has no effect, as it auto scrolls back to the counter. Can the background image be adjusted to show properly in all orientations?

I am using iPhone 7 and iOS 10.2 beta.

Comment: There is nothing "up". The countdown is the whole page. Can't see any bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was expecting it would let me see the "Winter" text.

Comment: Oh you mean the background image. Well, your device orientation is wrong (i.e. not fitting that site at least) try to rotate it.

Comment: (this is how I see it on my mobile device: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i5eCs.jpg)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm going to change this to a feature request that requests we use a placeholder for mobile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hu? Clearly, when held in landscape the page breaks. One cannot scroll up to see all the text. You can't say "orientation is wrong" - a site should work both ways, no?

Comment: Was the page meant to work on mobile? Most is the site isn't and certainly not the winterbash pages last year. Not sure if a countdown deserves that much attention. They'd better put effort in things that we use the rest of the year.